# How I read another Android application's file?

Tags: android, file, android-context

I have two applications.They have to communicate through a file.
I know I can write a file on Android using Context.openFileOutput and pass it `MODE_WORLD_READABLE|MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. But how can I find the file in another application?

---

Sorry , I have found the solution. In another application, you just need get appropriate Context, then you can do the same things.The API is `Context.createPackageContext`.

Comment: Do you mean the files in res folder or in data?

Comment: if you have found an answer, instead of updating the question just post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

**in owner process**

```
final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putInt(....)
edit.commit();
```

**in other process**

```
final Context remoteContext = createPackageContext(OWNER_PACKAGE_NAME,  Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
final SharedPreferences pref = remoteContext.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE |  Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
pref.getInt(...)
```

Comment: final Context remoteContext = getContext().createPackageContext("com.mygames",  getContext().CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
gives an error message Packagemanager.NameNotFoundException. I expect a build path has to be given somewhere for the 'other process' package name. however, you won't know what the path  is going to be for your users. is there a way to get around this exeption? I've been trying to find a way for one app to read another's sharedpreferences file (from the same publisher) for some time and haven't found the answer even at stack overflow.